# Meaning - I am no atheist, in fact further from that

Tags: meaning

I wrote this sentence -

> I am no atheist, in fact further from that.

When you read this sentence what meaning you get? I wanted to mean that "I am no atheist. In fact I am quite opposite. Though I have not exclusively said that I am opposite of atheist. But yet I just gave a hint".

Am I right?

Comment: "further from that" does not convey your intended meaning. Why not use "just the opposite"

Comment: "I am not an atheist; in fact, nothing could be further from the truth" is a possibility, but it's much wordier than simply saying "just the opposite", since that's ultimately what you mean.

Comment: We need the context to figure this one out. "That" almost definitely refers to something previously in the text.

Answer (score 1):

1. You state you are not an atheist
2. You state you are more distant from that

The sentence is confusing because "more" comes in here. More that what?
(1) describes an absolute value where (2) is a relative one.

CarSmack and Roger gave you good examples of opposite (and absolute) values.

Comment: Yes, you should always provide antecedents for your pronouns. "Further from that" does not mean anything, because you have not established what "that" is, or how much further you are away from it. If you do not provide antecedents in the same sentence, they should be in a sentence you just mentioned in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is "farthest from the truth".

To say I am a tolerant man would be farthest from the truth.

Or as Roger says, *Nothing could be further from the truth.*